# Error while starting Eclipse

Tags: android

I updated the SDK, as well as "Eclipse".

On start of eclipse each time it gives the following warning:

[image]

[image]

The 1st 2 plug-in's are unsigned. Does this cause a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. There seemed to be some un-signed components while installing the update.
Got the signed and proper updates from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Earlier I was updating the components from Eclipse itself.

Comment: Your answer is the wrong and it leads to wrong direction, actual reason is that latest SDK plugins is not compatible with the ADT plugins below revision17. see my answer.

Comment: I did what you said earlier, then re-started ECLIPSE... Still the same warning. When i installed the .exe from the link, it stopped giving the warning. How am I mis-guiding? This worked for me, I am suggesting another alternative than the normal update from ECLIPSE directly. If there is a problem updating from ECLIPSE, then try this option!!!

Answer (score 3):

Your ADT plugins is not compatible to SDK
You have to update the ADT to revision17

[Here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#updating) is a steps for update the ADT

**Update**
I had same issue before two days but after updating ADT to revision17 it is working fine.

There are 4 parts of the Developer Tools

1. Android DDMS
2. Android Development Tools (ADT)
3. Android Hierarchy Viewer
4. Android Trace view

If you update the ADT which is the second option then it will be okay.
Then updation of other options is depends on you.

Comment: I guess i had updated the "TraceViewer" too.. I think that would have caused the problem.

Comment: ADT plugins is okay, no need to update other component. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks, the problem is now solved. The 1st 2 files in the above (2nd) image were "unsigned". I downloaded the ADT.exe from the developer site (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), and now it's not giving any error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the sdk. In Eclipse goto Windows> Android SDK Manager and install the updates available

Comment: I had updated the SDK manager. The problem was with ADT itself. Some of the files were un-signed hence giving error.

Comment: Try to uninstall the ADT plugin and install again. Even I faced the same issue and got resolved by trying this.Please check the ANDROID SDK TOOLS revision version is 17 in SDK Manager. Try "Check for updates " again.